# How many balls were thrown with the power of two choices?

Tags: probability

I have an engineering problem that can be mapped to a balls and bins problem, and I would like to know how to go about figuring it out.

$m$ balls are thrown into $n$ bins; $n$ is known $m$ is unknown. The balls were thrown using [the power of two choices](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/handbook2001.pdf) to distribute the balls more. I choose two bins at random (most likely without replacement) and see their height. I would like to estimate a range of how many balls were thrown.

All the examples I've seen give $m$ and $n$, and figure out an upper bound of the highest bin.

---

**Update**: If it helps any, the [paper linked above](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/handbook2001.pdf) gives a bound on the maximum height of each bin to $\ln(\ln(n)))/\ln(2)(1 +o(1)) + (m/n)$.

From my understanding of little-oh, $o(1)$ can pretty much be eliminated; and $n$ is a constant, so we set $c = n \cdot \ln(\ln(n))/\ln(2)$. Which means, given a height of a bin $h_i$, $$m \geq n*h_i - c $$

From my experimental results, it looks like the *lower bound* of the height of each bin is similarly stated. Thus I **suspect** $$nh_i - c \leq m \leq nh_i + c$$

With 10 bins, that is a range of $\pm 12.03$; and with $100$ bins it is a range $\pm 220.33$

But of course, I have *two* samples, $h_i$ and $h_j$; giving me
 $$n \cdot \max(h_i,h_j) - c \leq m \leq n \cdot \min(h_i,h_j) + c$$

Again, this is suspected; not proven. And it doesn't take into account the likelihood of getting two bins with those particular heights.